# Sharing an sqlite database between iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Is this possible? Can I copy a database to the user's home directory and then access it with more than a single program? I'm guessing the answer is 'no', as it would make copy and paste pretty trivial, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. This is what OpenClip did (well, not with databases), but 2.1 broke it: http://gizmodo.com/5040509/iphone-21-will-break-openclip-copy-and-paste-between-apps.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Bugger. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that two apps with the same top level bundle identifiers (E.G., com.mycompany.xxx and com.mycompany.yyy) could access each other's shared data.  I'll see if I can find some documentation from Apple on this...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. If that works I'd be set. It seems to work in simulator, but I'm still waiting for my developer application to be approved to test it on the iPhone proper.